# Provide a fake CKEDITOR while unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have 2 projects ..

```
.
├── dependency-project
│   └── ckeditor
│       └── ckeditor.js
└── my-project
    ├── app
    │   └── script.js
    ├── karma.conf.js
    └── test
        └── script.test.js
```

`dependency-project` contains `ckeditor.js`, and both applications are served from the same web server.

So `my-project` can access `ckeditor.js` via `http://localhost:8080/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` based on how I have configured the web server.

This setup works fine when using the apps via a browser. But for unit testing, I'm getting an error when my tests try to use `CKEDITOR`.

Note: I'm not referencing `ckeditor.js` in my `karma.conf.js`, I'd like to define a fake if possible.

This is the error, is there a way i can stub/mock `CKEDITOR` here? ..

```
      PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CKEDITOR
```

`script.js` ..

```
document.getElementById('myElement').addEventListener('click', _editingTextStart);

function _editingTextStart() {
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
}
```

`script.test.js` ..

```
'use strict';
describe('script', function() {

  var sandbox;
  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should setup ckeditor', function() {
    var event = new Event('click');
    document.getElementById('myElement').dispatchEvent(event);
  });
});
```

Comment: this seems so weird to me in so many aspects. why would you setup 2 projects like this anyway. and why do you think you have access to a CKEDITOR instance if you aren't even trying to load the library in karma?

Comment: i dont expect to have access to a ckeditor instance, im asking can i fake it somehow

Comment: What do you want to test exactly? It's probably easier to mock the functions accessing ckeditor than to mock the whole thing. You could of course mock the object like `window['CKEDITOR'] = { disableAutoInline: false };` and then expect it to change to true in your test. But really, why don't you just include the library in karma? Just because you use it in your tests doesn't mean you have to serve it in that project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to mock the object itself using:

```
window['CKEDITOR'] = { disableAutoInline: false };
```

in the test setup.